# Specify colour for cv::drawContours()

Tags: opencv

I have following simple piece of OpenCV code to detect contours in a greyscale image and to save the detected ones into a file raw_contours.png:

```
cv::findContours(*srcImg,contours,cv::RETR_LIST,cv::CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS);
cv::Mat drawing = cv::Mat::zeros( srcImg->size(), CV_8UC3 );
cv::drawContours(drawing,contours, -1, (255, 255, 255), 1);
cv::imwrite("C:\\tmp\\raw_contours.png",drawing);
```

This works fine except the fact that the result is a balck image with dark-blue contours drawn in it. The fourth parameter `(255,255,255)` should set the colour to white, but this does not work.

So...any idea what is wrong here or how to change the colour successfully?

Thanks!

Comment: try `cv::Scalar(255,255,255)` instead. (and curious, what your 'tuple' evaluates to in c++, it probably only sets the 1st channel, b)

Comment: @berak Great, this was the solution! No idea where I got this weird example from...thank you!